# Cross-domain response.redirect with URL rewrite rules and SSL certificate

Tags: asp-classic, url-rewriting, cross-domain

I have a perfectly functioning URL rewriting to remove the file extension. But when I use `response.redirect`, the URL rewrite doesn't take place. Oddly, this occurs only when the URL is using the full path, not relative. For example:

```
response.redirect("http://example.com/page")
```

gives me **http://example.com/page.asp**

whereas `response.redirect("/page")` is fine.

URL rewrite code:

```
<rule name="rewrite asp">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" negate="true" pattern="(.*).asp" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.asp" />
</rule>
```

I need to use the full path because I'm going from one domain to another. Any ideas?

Comment: doh, sorry, it's Server.Transfer

Comment: ah sure, yeah I tried that one and it didn't work.

Comment: As a last suggestion, try add a querystring, e.g. 'response.redirect("http://example.com/page/?test=1")'

Comment: That gives me http://example.com/page.asp?test=1. I'm thinking it has to be at the receiving end, where the URL rewriting isn't being triggered.

Comment: I can not see any rewrite rule configuration sample on this question about rewrite rule, this is so weird :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maybe try something like this:

```
/redirect?url=<%=Server.URLEncode("http://example.com/page.asp")%>
```

then in redirect.asp:

```
<%sSomeExternalURL = URLDecode(Request.QueryString("url"))%>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=<%=sSomeExternalURL%>">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

<%
Function URLDecode(str) 
    str = Replace(str, "+", " ") 
    For i = 1 To Len(str) 
        sT = Mid(str, i, 1) 
        If sT = "%" Then 
            If i+2 < Len(str) Then 
                sR = sR & _ 
                    Chr(CLng("&H" & Mid(str, i+1, 2))) 
                i = i+2 
            End If 
        Else 
            sR = sR & sT 
        End If 
    Next 
    URLDecode = sR 
End Function
%>
```

Comment: You helped get there although the problem was not laid out properly in my question. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating? I'm glad I could help, but I'm sure other people might want to know what the solution was.

Comment: Sure. I didn't consider that this would have any effect, but the domain that is being redirected to has an SSL certificate. So there's also an other rewrite rule for that. The problem was ultimately solved by redirecting to `https://example.com/page`.